# Solr data missing from full import on "Error getting file length for segments_XX"

Tags: solr, lucene

Getting below warning in solr 6.1.0 full import

> LukeRequestHandler
>
> Error getting file length for [segments_1m]
>
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: solr/example/techproducts/solr/techproducts/data/index/segments_1m

around 70k out of 8.5L data records are missing from solr.
In Solr 5.5 this issue was reported but fixed in that version. Still facing this issue in solr 6.1.0.
Pleases refer:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8793

Comment: do you really still have the error message? I think the fix was just changing the level to WARN

Comment: It may help if you commit the pending documents: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/update?commit=true